nodejs перезапись участка файла
Как в nodejs перезаписать участок файла, не создавая дополнительные файлы и не читая все данные в память?
let filename= '123.txt';
const fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'w+');
fs.writeSync(fd, Buffer.from('123'), 0, 3, 5);
fs.closeSync(fd);

Ожидается, что данный код перезапишет 3 байта файла, начиная с 6, но он полностью стирает содержимое и вставляет 5 нулевых байт в начало, если же поставить флаг a+, то запись идет всегда в конец файла.

Необходимо использовать флаг r+
